# Configuring static files in OSQA development environment

Tags: python, django, static, osqa

I am using virtual machine with Ubuntu and Bitnami OSQA stack. It works fine. But if I try to debug it under PyCharm it doesn't. Static files become inaccessible, e.g.

```
/osqa/m/default/media/style/style.css
```

Error 404. As I understand, static files should be served automatically because the django.contrib.staticfiles module is used (but not sure, how to check this?).

Project settings in PyCharm are default, but after a very long investigations I replaced DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE value from settings onto OSQA.settings in order to fix empty MODULE_LIST error. I suppose the problem with static files can be fixed just as easy? I am novice in Python and Django